# Django + DRF как через POST запрос привезать текущего пользователя к записи

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, model, permissions

Есть такой вопрос, Django + DRF я создаю модель, скажем такую.

файл models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Текст')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/store/", blank=True, verbose_name='Фото')
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Время создания')
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Последнее обновление')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публикация')

    def __str__(self):
    return f'Id {self.id}:  {self.name}'
```

К ней сериализатор, файл serializers.py

```
class BooksSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

Далее, создаю представление, скажем такое, файл views.py

```
class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer
```

Унаследовавшись от класса ModelViewSet я автоматически имею
все CRUD операции к модели.

При помощи настройки привилегий, я могу сделать проверку
на то аутентифицирован пользователь или нет, и таким образом
давать доступ только тем кто вошел в систему.

```
class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer
    permission_classes = {permissions.IsAuthenticated}
```

Если я хочу чтобы аутентифицированный пользователь получал
только те записи, которые он сам и создал, то я могу переопределить
метод get_queryset() и сделать проверку на пользователя.

```
class BookList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = BooksSerializer
queryset = Book.objects.all()
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return Book.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

Вот мой вопрос, как мне сделать обратный процесс,как я могу сделать
так чтобы создаваемые пользователем записи в модели Book через метод
POST были привязаны к нему, что бы сущьность пользователя автоматически
вносила с новой записью в модели, изините если вопрос глупый, я только
учусь.

Answer (score 2):

Можешь например так:

```
class CreateBookAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Либо можешь переопределить метод creare в сериализаторе и там при подвязывать пользователя.

Comment: Можно так, но я бы лучше передавал пользователя в сериализатор вместе с данными, чтобы можно было при необходимости сделать проверки, связанные с пользователем

Comment: Как вариант, я и предложил 2 варианта